# mysqli_connect gets root (user) instead of my username

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

```
Success... Localhost via UNIX socket 
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Can anyone tell me why I get the above `'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` when I am attempting connection with my username and password.

Is there a problem with my code or the server I am using that fails to recognize my user name and password?

I actually copied this code from replies on one of the many sites I have visited.

```
<?php

/* Set Variables */

$host="localhost";
$db="beebot_memdb";
$username="beebot_weber";
$pass="xxxxxxxxxx";

/* Attempt to connect */

$mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pass,$db);

if (mysqli_connect_error())
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> using password: NO

means that you tried to authentificiate wihout giving a passwort.

Comment: Why does it say 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when I am attempting connection with my username and password.  Also, I see a lot of mentions to giving the root a password.  Is that done with a command line?